# react mui-datatables 4, can't customize style

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I'm using `"mui-datatables": "^4.2.2",` `"@mui/material": "^5.6.1",` i tried to customize style like this :

[Customize Styling official doc](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables#customize-styling)

```
// MUI DATATABLES

import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { CacheProvider } from "@emotion/react";
import createCache from "@emotion/cache";

const options = {
  filter: false,
  filterType: "checkbox",
  download: true,
  sort: false,
  responsive: "vertical", // standard | vertical | simple
  selectableRows: "multiple",
  selectableRowsOnClick: false,
  print: true,
  viewColumns: false,
  searchOpen: false,
  search: true,
  page: 0,
  pageSize: 10,
  // rowsPerPage: 10,
  rowsPerPageOptions: [],
  textLabels: {
    body: {
      noMatch: "Aucun enregistrement correspondant trouvé",
    },
    pagination: {
      next: "Suivant",
      previous: "Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent",
      rowsPerPage: "Rows per page:",
      displayRows: "sur",
    },
    toolbar: {
      search: "Recherche",
      downloadCsv: "Télécharger CSV",
      print: "Imprimer",
      viewColumns: "Afficher les colonnes",
      filterTable: "Tableau de filtrage",
    },
    selectedRows: {
      text: "ligne(s) sélectionnée(s)",
      delete: "Supprimer",
      deleteAria: "Supprimer les lignes sélectionnées",
    },
  },
  customToolbarSelect: (selectedRows) => console.log(selectedRows),
};

const muiCache = createCache({
  key: "mui",
  prepend: true,
});

const getMuiTheme = () =>
  createTheme({
    components: {
      MUIDataTableBodyCell: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            backgroundColor: "#000000",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

and then inside the react function component i return :

```
 <CacheProvider value={muiCache}>
              <ThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme}>
                <MUIDataTable
                  title={"Accueil"}
                  data={data}
                  columns={columns}
                  options={options}
                />
              </ThemeProvider>
            </CacheProvider>
```

I should have a dark body cell, but nothing is changed

[image]

How can i fix this issuer ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the solution to the problem:

"mui-datatables": "^4.2.2"
"@mui/material": "^5.9.0"

> ```
> import MUIDataTable from "mui-datatables";
> import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
>
> const XTable = ({columns, header, data}) => {
>
>   const getMuiTheme = () =>
>     createTheme({
>       components: {
>         MuiTableCell: {
>           styleOverrides:{ root: {
>             padding: '8px',
>             backgroundColor: '#CDCAC6',
>           }}
>         },
>         MuiToolbar: {
>           styleOverrides:{regular: {
>             minHeight: '8px',
>           }}
>         }
>       }
>     });
>
>   return(
>       <ThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme()}>
>             <MUIDataTable 
>               title={header} 
>               data={data} 
>               columns={columns} 
>               options={options} 
>             />
>       </ThemeProvider>
>     );
> } 
>
> export default XTable;
> ```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why it works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.

Answer (score 0):

me helped only downgrading to "3.8.5"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32246676)